# Error while replacing string with array in react state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I have below react code it works fine when variable logs is string, i.e. commented code, but as soon as I replace logs with array I am getting the error,

```
import React from "react";
export default class WelcomeComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        // logs :''
        logs: []
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    var socket = io('http://localhost:11001');
    socket.on('news', (data) => {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        this.setState({
            logs: this.state.logs.push(data)
            // logs: data + this.state.logs
        });
    });
}
render() {
    return (<div> {this.state.logs}</div>);
}
}
```

With logs as a array it gives the below error,

Uncaught TypeError: _this2.state.logs.push is not a function(…)

Can anyone please help.

Comment: if you do a `console.log(this.state.logs)` in your `componentDidMount`, what does it return?

Comment: Its showing as 1, not sure why though

Comment: You're setting logs to be the result of `.push()`, which will be the length of the array, so it get's set to a number.  The next time you try to update the state, you will call `push` on a number and error.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use immutability approach:

```
 socket.on('news', (data) => {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        const newLogs = [...this.state.logs, data]
        this.setState({
            logs: newLogs
            // logs: data + this.state.logs
        });
    });
```

Comment: It Worked, Thanks. I was following, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html  Not sure of the reason, I will read documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the state of the component directly, which is a big nope. Try [React Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)

```
import React from "react";
import update from 'react-addons-update';

export default class WelcomeComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        // logs :''
        logs: []
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    var socket = io('http://localhost:11001');
    socket.on('news', (data) => {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        this.setState({
            logs: update(this.state.logs, {$push: [data]});
        });
    });
}
render() {
    return (<div> {this.state.logs}</div>);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shota. Performance wise what to prefer using update or immutability approach like rob suggested above. I am currently reading the documentation and following it, I guess it requires a more deeper dive.

Comment: If you are not really building something that needs very dedicated performance optimization you don't need to worry about it. Otherwise, if you want to have some very dedicated solution, take a look at: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/